# How can I divide the array?

Tags: java

I have a block of code like the one below. As for the else condition, I want to add what I add to the `totalDates` array as if it were a single array.

```java
public ResponseEntity<?> findByHourlyAggregated(@PathVariable String hours) {

    HashMap<Date, List<Post>> map = new HashMap<Date, List<Post>>();
    Date startDate = new Date();
    Date date = new Date();
    Timestamp endDate = null;
    Date endDate = new Date();
    List<Post> postAll = (List<Post>) findAll();
    Instant afterHours = null;
    List<Post> totalDates = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Date> allDates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Date firstDate;
    firstDate = postAll.get(0).getDateCreated();
    for (Post p : postAll) {      
        startDate = p.getDateCreated(); //2020-08-11 10:42:08.0 , time of incoming data
        date = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Integer.parseInt(hours))); // Tue Aug 11 12:42:08 EET 2020 
        endDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime()); // 2020-08-11 12:42:08.0, add the parameter entered with the incoming data
        
        if (firstDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime() && startDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
            totalDates.add(p);
            
        }
        else {
            map.put(firstDate, totalDates);
            firstDate.setTime(endDate.getTime()); // value of new values when values in range are exhausted
            date = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Integer.parseInt(hours))); // Adds 2 hours
            endDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I separate the date value from the Post data according to the value from the parameter. For example, when the value 2 is entered, I need to assign values between 10-12 to one array and values between 12-14 to the other array. As a result, I want to get a print out.

```
{
    "2020-08-11T10:42:08.000+03:00": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "postBody": "Post 1",
            "author": "michael",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T10:42:08.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "postBody": "Post 2",
            "author": "jam",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T10:45:21.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "postBody": "Post 3",
            "author": "jim",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T10:57:33.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "postBody": "Post 4",
            "author": "dwight",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T11:02:35.000+03:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "postBody": "Post 5",
            "author": "scott",
            "dateCreated": "2020-08-11T11:52:51.000+03:00"
        }
    ]
}

2020-08-12T12:42:08.000+03:00": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }], 

            ....
```

Comment: Can you please provide more clarity on your question?

Comment: what is the question ? Your totalDates list is not divided. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: Yes, I want to divide it as the first index when I enter the else condition and then as the second index when you enter it again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should initialize totalDates after map.put statement in else block. Then posts will be divided into different totalDates list object.

```
map.put(firstDate, totalDates);
totalDates = new ArrayList<>(); // This will create a new ArrayList instance
```

**Update 1**

Consider changing your HashMap

```
HashMap<Date, List<Post>> map = new HashMap<Date, List<Post>>();
```

to

```
HashMap<String, List<Post>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Post>>();
```

The keys in the map should be immutable. Using String as key would ensure that. You can then change the put logic to -

```
map.put(firstDate.toString(), totalDates);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you saying the part of totalDates.add(p)? Could you please write a short code?

Comment: Thank you. It's works. I keep the first date data in FirstDate data. I replace firstDate with lastDate whenever it enters an else block. But the last changed firstDate data is written into the map. For example I want; {
     "2020-08-11_10": [... Posts created between 10-12 o'clock on August 11 ...],
     "2020-08-11_12": [... Posts created between 12-14 o'clock on August 11 ...],
     ...
} to be in the form

Comment: @MichaelScott Sorry, I didn't quite follow the question. Do you need map key format as 2020-08-11_10 instead of 2020-08-11T10:42:08.000+03:00 ? Also, can you please upvote the answer. I couldn't understand why was it downvoted.

Comment: I did not downvoted.It gives an error when I try to upvoted. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: There is firstDate data in the key section of the map. I mean this; For data between 10-12 hours
"2020-08-11T10: 42: 08.000 + 03: 00": [{}], (data between 10-12 hours)
"2020-08-11T12: 42: 08.000 + 03: 00": [{}], (data between 12-14 hours)
"2020-08-11T14: 42: 08.000 + 03: 00": [{}], (data between 14-16 hours)
...
 
But firstDate is the last to come firstDate for all data.
"2020-08-12T02: 42: 08.000 + 03: 00": [{}],
"2020-08-12T02: 42: 08.000 + 03: 00": [{}],
"2020-08-12T02: 42: 08.000 + 03: 00": [{}],
...